# Problems with sending data to database

Tags: php, html

Hi i am having some problem with sending data to the database when i send the  data it does say connected buy no data are found in the database . Am new to php ... please help .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Login File </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>


    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <form action="login_process.php" method="post">

                <legend><h1 style="color:red;">Form title </h1></legend>

                <div class="input-field col s6">

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <span class="help-block"></span>

                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="input-field col s6">

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <span class="help-block"></span>

                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">

                    </div>

                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

the connection file :

```
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'demo');

    if(!$connection) {

    die("Database connection failed". mysqli_error()); } else {echo "Connected";}

?>
```

and the process file :

```
<?php

require_once 'connection.php';

if($connection) {

    echo "<h1>Connected</h1>";

}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO user_tbl(username,password) VALUES ('$username','$password')";

    $result= mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    if (!$result) {

        die("Query failed");

    }

}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_tbl");
echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Have you created your table in the database yet? If not you will not create one in the code above. You will need CREATE TABLE for this.

Comment: yes i have created the table in phpmyadmin but still cant figure out whats wrong

Comment: When i submit data it says connected but the data doesn't show on the database

Comment: Have you checked your log yet?

Comment: what log ??  totally new to php ....

Comment: no errors even come up ..

Comment: that's because you are checking for a submit button named submit which does not exist.  See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with your form.

Your php script:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

is looking for a named variable which should be `name="submit"`

You are checking for a submit button named submit which does not exist.

Change this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="submit" />
```

Comment: Buddy ur a Star ..... Thats a lot for ur help it worked been sitting for 3 hours trying to figue it out .... Thanks a lot ...........